# Getting class and method names at runtime

Tags: c#

How to get the name of the class and the name of the method of this class at runtime. The code gets compiled and then obfuscated using some open source obfuscator. Here is an example:

```
class MainClass {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(Test));
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(Test.TestMethod));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void TestMethod() {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

The obfuscator renames classes and methods like this:

```
MainClass -> A
MainClass.Main -> A.a
Test -> B
Test.TestMethod -> B.a
```

When I run my code after compilation and obfuscation I get:

```
B
TestMethod
```

So the `nameof` works as expected for the class name, but doesn't work for the method name. How does the `nameof` work? What is the correct way to get the obfuscated names of the class and the method at runtime?

Comment: Why do you need to know?  Normally it is not a problem unless say you are making an API that you wish to publish and don't want certain types to be obfuscated (e.g. `IEndpoint.Send(IMessage)` ).  In which case I would back in the day, tell Obfuscator to exclude a particular class or method.

Comment: nameof() is run at compile time. You can probably use reflection to do this.

Comment: `nameof` is a compile-time feature, so it's particularly odd that `nameof(Test)` should yield `B`, unless the obfuscator performs source code rewriting. Regardless, if you want the name of a class at runtime, use `typeof(Test).Name`.

Comment: What does `GetType()` return?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
class MainClass {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var methodinfo = typeof(Test).GetMethod("TestMethod");
        var handle = methodinfo.MetaDataToken;
        MethodBase method = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(handle);
        string methodName = method.Name;
        string className = method.ReflectedType.Name;

        string fullMethodName = className + "." + methodName;
        Console.WriteLine(fullMethodName);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void TestMethod() {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```